# ntpdate does synchronisation with some offset always

Tags: linux, rhel, ntp, root

In RHEL, ntpdate always syncs time with some offset, even after firing the command hundreds of times with a frequency of firing once in a second.

Comment: Which ntp server are you using?

Comment: Define "some offset".  If it's a few milliseconds that's due to network jitter.  If it's seconds, then you have a problem in your local clock.  And BTW, this question belongs on [su] or [linux.se]

Comment: I am using a Symmetricom Time Server over a 10Gbps LAN, so network jitter is not a problem. Offsets are like +0.004988, +0,004592, +0.005621 (on Syncing every sec) ...    although the values are small, but the offset should go low after a number of Syncs right ??  and if I Sync after a longer duration(say an hour) the offset is of the order of +0.017845 ..    I am in need of a better precision than this.

Comment: my Local System is HP z600 workstation (http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01709707&prodSeriesId=3718663)

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing a few milliseconds of offset each time you sync.  This is normal.  See http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm#Q-ACCURATE-CLOCK